# Tutorial for opencv.js is not working for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, computer-vision

I installed the opencv.js file that they provide.
Set it inside the main folder and import it from there

Followed this instruction from the opencv itself (Emulating HTML DOM and Canvas): https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/de6/tutorial_js_nodejs.html

imported and installed the packages

[image]

Added these functions

[image]

And started using it

[image]

This returns an error that I need to provide valid canvas or img ID:

[image]

What should be the mistake that I am doing, how to make opencv.js work in node?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is that I used 'await loadImage' which will give me an image and not a promise.
Then I had another issue, it works the first time but when I try the second image it stops, the request is pending. So to avoid that I just required the cv like this:

[image]

And not with the loadOpenCV() function.

Hope I help someone with this